# Not receiving SYN/ACK after sending SYN using RAW socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, raw-sockets

I am sending TCP SYN packets (with no payload) to a webserver in the same network. I am using    [sniffex.c](http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c)
for capturing the packets .

The problem is that after I send a SYN packet, I do not receive the SYN/ACK packet from server.

In sniffex.c:
I have used my LAN IP as the source ip.
I have set the filter as **"tcp"** . 
I am sending to port 80

When i print the fields of the sent packet ,after i capture it using sniffex , all fields are printed correctly, hence i assume that the structure of the sent packet is such that the server can understand it.

When I connect to the webserver using browser, the SYN/ACK is received successfully.

Another related query: how do I set the filter such that I get packets relating to this conversation (b/w my pc and webserver) only

I am using UBUNTU 14.04

**EDIT**: The c file with which I am trying to send the packet

```
#define __USE_BSD   /* use bsd'ish ip header */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* these headers are for a Linux system, but */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* the names on other systems are easy to guess.. */
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#define __FAVOR_BSD /* use bsd'ish tcp header */
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<memory.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

#define P 80        /* lets flood the sendmail port */

unsigned short      /* this function generates header checksums */
csum (unsigned short *buf, int nwords)
{
  unsigned long sum;
  for (sum = 0; nwords > 0; nwords--)
    sum += *buf++;
  sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
  sum += (sum >> 16);
  return ~sum;
}

int 
main (void)
{
  int s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
  printf("s=%d\n",s);   /* open raw socket */
  char datagram[4096];  /* this buffer will contain ip header, tcp header,
               and payload. we'll point an ip header structure
               at its beginning, and a tcp header structure after
               that to write the header values into it */
  struct ip *iph = (struct ip *) datagram;
  struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct ip));
  struct sockaddr_in sin;
            /* the sockaddr_in containing the dest. address is used
               in sendto() to determine the datagrams path */

  sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sin.sin_port = htons (P);/* you byte-order >1byte header values to network
                  byte order (not needed on big endian machines) */
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");

  memset (datagram, 0, 4096);   /* zero out the buffer */

/* we'll now fill in the ip/tcp header values, see above for explanations */
  iph->ip_hl = 5;
  iph->ip_v = 4;
  iph->ip_tos = 0;
  iph->ip_len = sizeof (struct ip) + sizeof (struct tcphdr);    /* no payload */
  iph->ip_id = htonl (54321);   /* the value doesn't matter here */
  iph->ip_off = 0;
  iph->ip_ttl = 255;
  iph->ip_p = 6;
  iph->ip_sum = 0;      /* set it to 0 before computing the actual checksum later */
  iph->ip_src.s_addr = inet_addr ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");/* SYN's can be blindly spoofed */
  iph->ip_dst.s_addr = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;
  tcph->th_sport = htons (2000);    /* arbitrary port */
  tcph->th_dport = htons (P);
  tcph->th_seq = random();/* in a SYN packet, the sequence is a random */
  tcph->th_ack = 0;/* number, and the ack sequence is 0 in the 1st packet */
  tcph->th_x2 = 5;
  tcph->th_off = 5;     /* first and only tcp segment */
  tcph->th_flags = TH_SYN;  /* initial connection request */
  tcph->th_win = htonl (65535); /* maximum allowed window size */
  tcph->th_sum = 0;/* if you set a checksum to zero, your kernel's IP stack
              should fill in the correct checksum during transmission */
  tcph->th_urp = 0;

  iph->ip_sum = csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->ip_len >> 1);

/* finally, it is very advisable to do a IP_HDRINCL call, to make sure
   that the kernel knows the header is included in the data, and doesn't
   insert its own header into the packet before our data */

                /* lets do it the ugly way.. */
    int one = 1;
   // const int *val = &one;
    if (setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &one, sizeof (one)) < 0)
      printf ("Warning: Cannot set HDRINCL!\terrno = %d\n",errno);




 // while (1)
   // {
      if (sendto (s,        /* our socket */
          datagram, /* the buffer containing headers and data */
          iph->ip_len,  /* total length of our datagram */
          0,        /* routing flags, normally always 0 */
          (struct sockaddr *) &sin, /* socket addr, just like in */
          sizeof (sin)) < 0)        /* a normal send() */
    printf ("error\n");
      else
    printf ("SUCCESS\n\n\n\n");
    //}
char buffer[8192];
memset (buffer, 0, 8192);
int n;
//while(n=read (s, buffer, 8192) > 0)
//{
//printf("n=%d\n",n);

 //printf ("Caught tcp packet: %s\n", buffer);
 //memset (buffer, 0, 8192);
//}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first step should be to use another program like wireshark or tcpdump to check if (1) your packet is actually hitting the wire and (2) if a reply is actually being sent or not.  Then you should show your actual code.

Comment: @JohnHascall I did that just know and could not find that packet in wireshark. But sniffex is able to capture the packet and displays all fields correctly .Please take a look again at the question , i have added the c file in which i am sending the packet.

Comment: If sniffex captured the packet that i sent, does it not ensure that the packet hit the wire?

Comment: I see one error right away: `iph->ip_off = 0 /*10*/;`

Comment: I changed that , now that packet is being detected in wireshark but still there is no reply. I noticed that the SEQ was 0, is this normal?I mean shouldn't it be 23456 or random() (as i tried later)

Comment: The other issue I found was with the TCP checksum -- on my system at least, it did NOT insert the correct checksum for me, once I computed a correct TCP checksum, I received a reply packet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76282/discussion-between-jps-and-john-hascall).

Comment: Though it is not the problem here, but if someone else comes in future and doesn't have any problem with code and still doesn't receive any replies (The question), it is possible that you are sending to a filtered port. You won't get any replies on filtered port. You can check that using `nmap <dest ip/name>`. It will show you all closed/open ports and not the filtered ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Summary of chat session]
In addition to the iph->ip_off issue, you may need to compute the TCP checksum yourself (your O/S may not do it for you).   Useful info is here: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPChecksumCalculationandtheTCPPseudoHeader-2.htm and http://www.netfor2.com/tcpsum.htm

Also `tcph->th_seq = htonl(23456);` may be useful.